# Check if file or folder is open before delete

Tags: java

- How to check if a file / folder is open before i try to delete it.
- Am deleting it programmatically.. before deleting, need to check whether its opened or not
- I want something like this,

  ```
              if(file/folder is open){
                 //do not delete it
              }else{
                 //delete it
               }
  ```

  I tried the below set of two codes, but nothing is working

  ```
       File scrptFile=new File(dirFile);
       boolean isFileUnlocked = false;
  try {
      org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(scrptFile);
      isFileUnlocked = true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
      isFileUnlocked = false;
  }

  if(isFileUnlocked){
      // Do stuff you need to do with a file that is NOT locked.
      System.out.println("file is not locked");
  } else {
      // Do stuff you need to do with a file that IS locked
      System.out.println("file is locked");
  }


         File file = new File(dirFile);
  FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
  // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
  FileLock lock = channel.lock();
  try {
      lock = channel.tryLock();
      // Ok. You get the lock
      System.out.println("Ok. You get the lock");
  } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
      // File is open by someone else
      System.out.println("File is open by someone else");
  } finally {
      lock.release();
  }
  ```

Comment: Interesting idea, but given the fact that a file lock is OS dependent (and under some OS with multiple different approaches) it might be difficult to ascertain in a clean way. The best way is to try. File#delete returns false if it couldn't delete the file for some reason

Comment: Can u check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341505/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-open-by-another-process-java-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352010/check-if-a-file-is-open-before-reading-it

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Apache commons io api,

```
  boolean flagFileNotInUse = false;
try {
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(yourFile);
    flagFileNotInUse = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    flagFileNotInUse = false;
}
```

// Then check value of flagFileNotInUse ,

```
  flagFileNotInUse = true, means file not in use
  flagFileNotInUse = false, means file in use
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clear if you either name the bool flagFileNotInUse or swap the values of the flag?

Comment: @RFerwerda : Please refer to updated post.

Comment: the above code is working for folder but not for file @DarkKnight