# Make sure file is not opened in Java with without triggering exception if not created

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a procedure that makes sure a file is not opened in java.
I was following this reference:

[How to check if a file is open by another process (Java/Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341505/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-open-by-another-process-java-linux)

But I keep getting exceptions because the first time I go into the procedure, the file is not yet created, so it triggers an exception. And on the other hand if I change it and add a filenotfound execption, this procedure stops working, meaning it does not trigger exception if a file is open.

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

```
     private boolean isFileClosed(File file) {  
        boolean closed;
        Channel channel = null;
        try {
            channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
            closed = true;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            closed = false;
        } finally {
            if(channel!=null) {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // exception handling
                }
            }
        }
        return closed;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code? We can't help you without seeing your approach and progress.

Comment: I used the code I referenced. The problem is that the first time I reach there is when this file is not yet created, and then I get an exception that I don't want to get.

Comment: Which one? The one from the question? From one of the answers? ....?

Comment: Adding it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: What's your expectation when the file does not exist yet? Should the routine pause or return a specific value?

Comment: If the file does not exist, that means that it's 100% not open, you can simply handle the creation of the file in your catch clause and then do the writing in the finally clause

Comment: When the file does not exist I expect it to handle it as if its not open. @MonsterDruide1
What happens is that I get a file not found exception that make my procedure act as if the file is opened...

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between the different exception types:

```java
private boolean isFileClosed(File file) {  
        boolean closed;
        Channel channel = null;
        try {
            channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
            closed = true;
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            closed = true;
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            closed = false;
        } finally {
            if(channel!=null) {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // exception handling
                }
            }
        }
        return closed;
}
```